# Queries using LIKE wildcards in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to perform a small SQL server search in my ASP.NET web project. My database is not big so I think it's better not to use full-text-search.

I want to perform a simple search like this:

```
select * from mytable where columnA LIKE '%something%'
```

I can use `=` in the following way:

```
select * from mytable where columnA='"+myVariable+"'
```

but how can I use a variable instead of `%something%` in the LIKE phrase?
Is this correct:

`LIKE '"+%myVariable%+"'`?

Comment: Correct but also very bad. Concatenating strings to make SQL statements can leave you wide open to SQL injection. Supposing myVariable has value `';drop table mytable;`? Look at parameterized queries or one of the Linq varieties for interacting with a DB

Comment: @spender : security validation should be done before an query execution anyway so this is not a question of query itself

Comment: @sll I don't buy it. It's difficult to "security validate" strings that are going to be mixed into SQL statements. It's better simply not to do it.

Comment: dear friends, I found the right answer thanks to your quick replies

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use:

```
where columnA LIKE '%' + myVariable + '%'
```

Comment: Why you are used different brackets?

Comment: I think you are talking about the single and double quotes. I used it as an example from your query given in the question, like this: `select * from mytable where columnA='"+myVariable+"'`. So in this query if you want to use `LIKE` then add `%` after the single quote (`'`) and similarly close it.

Answer (score 9):

```
WHERE
columnName LIKE '%' + myVarCharVariable +'%'
```

Answer (score 5):

I just tried this and found you can do as below:

```
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE column LIKE '%'+@var+'%'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this query:

```
select * from tablename where colname like '%' + @varname + '%'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @myVariable varchar(MAX)
SET @myVariable = 'WhatYouAreLookingFor'
SELECT * FROM mytable 
  WHERE columnA LIKE '%' + @myVariable + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else stumbles into this post like I did. On SSMS 2012 with a SQL 2012 Server back end I was able to use code as follows without issues.

```
Declare @MyVariable

Set @MyVariable = '%DesiredString%'

Select *

From Table_A

Where Field_A like @MyVariable
```

Then each time you want to change the Desired String just change it at the Set statement.

I know this post was made prior to 2012 that is why I am mentioning it in case someone with a newer setup looks up this post.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE columnA LIKE '%" + myVariable + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about sql injection, try something like this instead.  It's more complex, but it works and should satisfy security requirements. Let's say someone passed a value into your stored procedure using a parameter called "@searchstring".

```
DECLARE @searchString nvarchar(100) = 'test',
    @SQL nvarchar(max),
    @foundSearchHit bit,
    @paramdef nvarchar(max) = '@foundSearchHit bit OUTPUT'

SET @searchstring = '%' + @searchString + '%'

SET @SQL = '
SELECT TOP 1 @foundSearchHit = 1
FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] like ' + 
    QUOTENAME(@searchString,'''') 
EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, @paramdef, @foundSearchHit = @foundSearchHit OUTPUT

SELECT @foundSearchHit
```

That should do the trick.